# Neo4j - Deleting of nodes now returns empty nodes

Tags: neo4j, diskspace, purge

I deleted about 400k of nodes and was a bit surprised to find that the disk space was not significantly reduced.

I have read the [Understanding database growth article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-database-growth/) on neo4j knowledge base and can see why this is. I still haven't figured out if you can use the [store-utils](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils) to remove the old deleted nodes caching some how without creating an actual copy of the full dataset.

After the deletes i now get strange results back in the browser when I select nodes.

[image: Select some nodes]

As you can see it seems like I get back some of the deleted nodes and they only contain an id. Obviously this is not what I want.

Question:

- Is there some way of purging the deleted nodes?
- Why am I getting back empty nodes?
- Is store-utils the way to go here or is it possible to manually delete som files from the `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Store-utils copies over the data in your db, ignoring the deleted nodes (or more specifically, the areas in memory that used to point to nodes but have since been deleted). I don't believe there's a way to otherwise get rid of those, unless of course you fill them in with new nodes. You definitely can't remove them simply through deleting files in the file system, if it were that easy Neo4j would be doing that for you.

As to your empty node issue, I believe that's separate. Sounds like you might have a bad query that's creating these, usually it tends to be a query using MERGE is a wrong way. Here's a knowledge base article on [understanding how MERGE works](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/), that may help. If you can't identify a bad use of MERGE in any of your queries, then you may need to add more detail about when these are being created, assuming that they increase in number.